# i'm having trouble creating the database using symfony framework

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-4.4

STRUCTURE:

Student: First name, last name ,date of birth, image.

class:name, section

course:name,description

grades:student,course,class

So i'm struggling to create this database in symfony with doctrine ORM , if someone can help with the entities(especially the foreign keys) it will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use the `maker` component to create your entities (`composer require maker --dev`). Also, the integration of Doctrine with Symfony is described [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html).

**FIRST**

```sh
bin/console make:entity Student  # then just answer the question
bin/console make:entity ClassRoom  # or anything different than "Class" as it looks like the "class" keyword
bin/console make:entity Course 
bin/console make:entity Grades
```

When creating the `Grades` entity, choose the type `ManyToOne` (or `OneToOne`, can't guess with your description) for  your three properties `student`, `course` and `classRoom`.

More information about [association mapping](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/association-mapping.html#association-mapping) here.

**NEXT**

Then open your entities and enhance your [`@Column`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/annotations-reference.html#column) and [`@ManyToOne`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/annotations-reference.html#manytoone) annotations.

Considers adding a [`@UniqueConstraint`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/annotations-reference.html#uniqueconstraint) on the `Grade` entity wrapping your three properties if needed.

Considers adding a [`@JoinColumn`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/annotations-reference.html#joincolumns) constraint under your three `Grade` properties.

**FINALLY**

```sh
bin/console make:migration
bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```